# Deploying Sails App on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, sails.js

Can any one help me with deploying a **SailsJS** app on **Openshift**?

I followed [How you get Sail.js running on Openshift](https://gist.github.com/mdunisch/4a56bdf972c2f708ccc6)

After making my changes and pushing it to the repo I get the status as successful but when I go to my link it says

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at kittylogintest-kittygame.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to deploy my sails application on openshift
Most of the steps mentioned in the link mentioned in my question will help

After following the steps i was getting an error stating permission denied for grunt-cli
I solved it by SSHing in to my app and then doing the npm install in app-root/runtime/repo

Hope this helps if some one stumbles on the same stair.